# MVC Partial load hiding URL

Tags: url, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I am new to MVC. I am doing some partial page loads using images to get to the links. In the example below, I do a partial render of the Features page. My reasoning is, I have a music player playing that i don't want to interrupt while the user navigates the site. So this all works great, but I have issues with the URLs now. The url www.mysite.com remains the same as the site is navigated. I am expecting to see www.mysite.com/features.  I am not understanding the url is not including the path when I link to pages this way. How can I get the url to display correctly?

```
@Html.Raw(@Ajax.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Features", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "content" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]","<img src=\"/images/menu_items/btnFeatures_on.png\" ... />"))
```

Thanks

Comment: Url shown in browser reflects current top level page browser navigated to... It looks like you want navigation happen (to change url) and not happen (to keep current page active) at the same time. This is somewhat hard to achieve requirement and you need to decide which behavior you want...

Comment: Side note: it looks like question should be tagged asp.net-mvc, not "model-view-controller" - please check details of the tags to confirm if they match framework/language you are using.

Comment: I want both. If i wanted to keep a music player running without regard to the url displayed, I could have used iFrames. I know this is possible, www.reverbnation.com does it.